Command in container failed: helpers/check-requirements.sh in DevContainer with VSCode
I tried to run one project with devcontainer in VSCode (mode: Rebuild without cache and reopen in container) and I'm getting this error:
[2024-05-20T19:27:02.595Z] 
[2024-05-20T19:27:02.596Z] Stop (10 ms): Run in container: test -x '/root/.vscode-server/bin/dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685/bin/helpers/check-requirements.sh'
[2024-05-20T19:27:02.598Z] Start: Run in container: '/root/.vscode-server/bin/dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685/bin/helpers/check-requirements.sh'
[2024-05-20T19:27:02.735Z] 
[2024-05-20T19:27:02.738Z] 
[2024-05-20T19:27:02.738Z] Exit code 1
[2024-05-20T19:27:02.738Z] Stop (140 ms): Run in container: '/root/.vscode-server/bin/dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685/bin/helpers/check-requirements.sh'
[2024-05-20T19:27:02.783Z] Command in container failed: '/root/.vscode-server/bin/dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685/bin/helpers/check-requirements.sh'
[2024-05-20T19:27:02.786Z] Exit code 1

My VSCode info:
Version: 1.89.1
Commit: dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685
Date: 2024-05-07T05:14:24.611Z (1 wk ago)
Electron: 28.2.8
ElectronBuildId: 27744544
Chromium: 120.0.6099.291
Node.js: 18.18.2
V8: 12.0.267.19-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 21.6.0

I tried with these DevContainer versions: 0.366.0, 0.354.0
Does anyone have this problem too? Does anyone know how to resolve?
OBS: I'm using a distroless docker image (to python). With a regular docker image I can run the devcontainer.

It's not recommend use the distroless docker image to run Dev Container.
Here is a complete explanation about why (reference here):

Distroless images are minimal images that do not include a package manager, shell or any other programs you would expect to find in a standard Linux distribution. This is great for security, but it can make things difficult when you need to install additional software or debug issues inside the container.
Dev containers feature relies on certain utilities being available in
the container, such as a shell to execute commands and scripts. If
these utilities are not available, as is the case with distroless
images, you may encounter issues.
The error message you're seeing suggests that the
check-requirements.sh script is failing because it can't find a shell
to run the script. This is expected behavior with a distroless image,
as they do not include a shell.
If you need the security benefits of a distroless image, you might
consider using a multi-stage Docker build. In the first stage, you can
use a full-featured base image to compile your application and install
dependencies. In the second stage, you can copy the compiled
application from the first stage into a distroless image. This way,
you get a minimal runtime image without sacrificing the developer
experience.
However, using a distroless image as a DevContainer base image is not
recommended, as it will likely lead to issues due to the missing
utilities.

